# Are there any point(s) of no return?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

I'm on chapter 6, and so far the game has warned me three times (twice through menus, once though a character literally saying "This is the point of no return!") that I'm reaching a point of no-return (or at least I won't be able to return for a while).

The first two were seemingly fake-outs. I haven't progressed past the third yet. Are there any real point(s) of no return?

Comment: The review I read said you can go back using a time travel mechanic of some sort.  Not sure if there's any hard and fast point of no return.

Comment: IIRC, in past FF games it would say stuff like that if there was a point where you would be stuck on a quest path, and unable to "come back to the town" for a while, to remind you to tie up loose ends, stock on potions etc before progressing. It could be something like that. Though I haven't played this new one.

Comment: after you leave Altissia and go to the third continent you can only do so in the story, so each chapter here is a point of no return, once you complete the story you can only travel back to Altissia and Lestallum (Duscae, etc)

Answer (score 1):

**No, not really**

There are chapters that you do not have access to the means of returning. You always come out of those chapters eventually and have one or all of your travel tools back at your beck and call. In general, there is no point where you cant ever go back and finish things you have missed.

It is worth mentioning there is a 3rd continent near the end of the game you access for the main story line. Once you have entered into the final chapter of that continent, Chapter 13, and finished it, there is no way to return to that continent.

Answer (score 0):

The only point of no return I've encountered is with the hotel in Altissia. When you go there as part of the main story you will have the option of getting a x3.0 experience bonus for resting. Once you decide to finish chapter then should you return at a later time using the umbra ability the bonus will have dropped to x1.5 instead.

Comment: This is incorrect. there are two vendors in Altissa, the one of the left is cheaper and gives 1.5x exp. The one on the right is 30k and gives 3.0x exp.

Comment: This is great news! Thanks for correcting me, I genuinely thought I had lost out on it... :-)

Answer (score -3):

I been through through this to as far as I can tell major point of no return getting on ya boat from my play through went from there to pretty much end game boss

Comment: What boat? This answer is vague and a bit hard to understand.

Comment: Its also inaccurate, as you can still return to other areas of the game later.